# Converting a nested JSON to transformed dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a particular Json file about data. I'd like to convert it to a Data Frame and apply some transformation. Here is the Json:

```
{
  "OuterVariable1": [
    {
      "InnerData": "car",
      "InnerList": {
        "wheels": {
          "cost-taxed": 231,
          "cost": 850
        },
        "engine": {
          "cost-taxed": 108,
          "cost": 286
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "InnerData": "van",
      "InnerList": {
        "frame": {
          "cost-taxed": 302,
          "cost": 250
        }
      }
    }, 
   ],

  "OuterVariable2": [
     {
      "InnerData": "truck",
      "InnerList": {
        "wheels": {
          "cost": 1400
        },
      }
    },
  ],
   ...
}
```

Here is what I want. Notice how `OuterVariable` is a new column, and we separate the entries for each `InnerList`.

| OuterVariable | InnerData | InnerList | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OuterVariable1 | "car" | "wheels" | 850 |
| OuterVariable1 | "car" | "engine" | 286 |
| OuterVariable1 | "van" | "frame" | 250 |
| OuterVariable2 | "truck" | "wheels" | 1400 |

How can I achieve this? I've used `jsonlite` to get an initial DataFrame and tried to use `lapply` to do some transformation with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the `rjson` package rather than `jsonlite` since the latter seems to treat the `year` property independently from the rest of the data for some reason.

I used a nested `lapply` approach, not sure how it performs on larger JSON data but it does the job:

```
library(rjson)
l <- fromJSON(json)

# Loop across each state (use index so we can keep track of the state name)
df_list <- lapply(seq_along(l),
                  function(i) {
                    # inner loop over every year entry
                    inner_list <- lapply(l[[i]], function(y) {
                      data.frame(OuterVariable = names(l)[i],
                                 InnerData = y$InnerData,
                                 InnerList = names(y$InnerList),
                                 Cost = sapply(y$InnerList, "[[", 1),
                    })
                    
                    # Bind together each "mini data.frame" to one per outerVariable
                    do.call("rbind", c(inner_list, make.row.names = FALSE))
                  })

# Bind together the per-outerVariable data.frames
df_result <- do.call("rbind", df_list)
```

Where `json` is the sample data you provided above.