# Extract JSON from read_html and convert to dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm trying scrape this url and store onto a dataframe, however I can't seem to be able to parse this? I tried several other post but so far it as failed.

```
tryCatch(
  {
    json_data <- read_html(glue ( "https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20210917" )) %>%
      html_node("#__NEXT_DATA__") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      fromJSON()
  },  error=function(e){}
  
) -> json_data


fromJSON(json_data)  %>% as.data.frame #failed

fromJSON(json_data$props)  %>% as.data.frame #failed
fromJSON(json_data$props)  %>% as.data.frame #failed
```

edit: I think I found the nested text I need but the json structure looks really messed up?

```
> str ( json_data$props$initialState )
 chr "{\"app\":{\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"theme\":\"DAY\",\"lang\":\"en\",\"country\":\"\",\"currency\":{\"id\":2781,\"n"| __truncated__
>
```

[Converting nested JSON to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576269/converting-nested-json-to-data-frame)
[Converting nested JSON file to R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839771/converting-nested-json-file-to-r-dataframe)
[Converting a nested JSON to transformed dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66814537/converting-a-nested-json-to-transformed-dataframe-in-r)
[Json read and convert to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931788/json-read-and-convert-to-dataframe)

Comment: That data is not flat, so it is not easily converted to a simple frame. I don't know the context or content of the different columns.

Comment: You may need to go through field by field (e.g., `props$initialI18nStore`, `props$pageProps`) and determine what it should look like in `data.frame` form. Once you know how each should look, write a function that takes it and munges each attribute individually and combines into a single frame in the end.

Comment: This is one huge mess of the data with multiple lists embedded in lists and some additional JSON mixed it.  It is best to have a strategy of exactly what data is important and what can be skipped before trying to decode this.